# Rails route shows in rake, responds in console,but browser shows undefined method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, haml

I cannot figure out why this route is not working. I have defined it, and it seems that it works everywhere, except for in the browser. I've attached screenshots with the relevant information.

The route for reports_path is showing undefined in the browser, but everywhere else it seems that it's working. What could be causing this?

[image: settings]
[image: error_screen]

Comment: can you please try in rails console `app.routes_path`

Comment: irb(main):005:0> app.routes_path
NoMethodError: undefined method `routes_path' for #<ActionDispatch::Integration::Session:0x007fcf01235438>
 from /opt/boxen/rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/testing/assertions/routing.rb:176:in `method_missing'
 from (irb):5

Comment: there is simple solution in routes.rb you can use `resources :reports` and then try it please remeber it should be in the top of `devise_for :users`

Comment: Please let me know if it is working or not

Comment: I don't need the resources though, I only have a few specific routes I need. Not only the restful ones which resource provides

Comment: A well formatted code sample is orders of magnitude easier to read than a screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rake routes shows `reports_path`, don't use `path` when naming you routes, you have one more named with path `reports_selling_agent_performance_path`, remove the `path`.

in this case:

```
match 'reports', to: 'reports#index', as: :reports
```

or

```
match 'reports', to: 'reports#index'
```

will work too, you use `as:` key only if you want to rename the path name that you'll use in code, for example:

```
match 'my_long_very_long_reports', to: 'reports#index', as: :reports
```

and you'll use `reports_path` in code instead of `my_long_very_long_reports_path`. Or in cases where you use keys like `:id` or others:

```
match 'my_reports/:id', to: 'reports#index', as: :reports
```

where `:id` will be id of the user for example that you'll send as params[:id]

Answer (score 1):

In your routes file, try changing `as: :reports_path` to `as: :reports` otherwise I think you'll need to use `reports_path_path` in your view.